# Hardening authorized_keys used in rsync backup

Tags: ssh, backup, rsync, authorized-keys, rsnapshot

- I'm trying to make a rootfs backup from `ServerA` on to `ServerB`.
- The connection is one way and is initialized from `ServerB` using `rsnapshot`.
- I have made a `backup` account on `ServerA` and enabled paswordless sudo only for `rsync`

What I'm trying to accomplish:

- Change the `authorized_keys` file on `ServerA`, so only the `rsync` command can be used via ssh.

On `ServerB` - `/etc/rsnapshot.conf` is setup to run `rsync` with the following args:

- `rsync_long_args --rsync-path="sudo rsync" --delete --numeric-ids --relative --delete-excluded`

I have tried the following on `ServerA`:

- `from="ServerB",command="sudo rsync *" ssh-ed25519 SSH-KEY`

But `rsnapshot` keeps crashing and giving IO error codes for `rsync`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer below and accept it (when the 48-hour delay period is over). You should *not* edit your question to include it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**!! Problem Solved !!**

Found out about rrsync --- `/usr/share/doc/rsync/scripts/rrsync`, copy it to wherever.

- `ServerA:authorized_keys --- command="sudo /usr/local/bin/rrsync -ro /backup"`

Since I'm keeping a copy of the backups on `ServerA`, I might as well rsync from them instead of using rsnapshot on `ServerB`. (This was my initial idea, but it doesn't work since there are duplicate files because of links that rsnapshot creates, I ended up having rsnapshot running both on `ServerA` and `ServerB`, to save backups from `ServerA` to a localDir on `ServerA` and also make remote snapshots from `ServerA` to `ServerB`.)

- Also changed the sudoers file on `ServerA`:

```
Defaults!/usr/local/bin/rrsync env_keep += "SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND"
backup ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/rrsync
```

- `rsync -ax --delete --numeric-ids --relative ServerA:/ /ServerB-backup/`

Now works as expected.

Note that the path on `ServerA` in the command above is relative to the rule set in authorized_keys.